# Multiple small files as input to map reduce

Tags: file, input, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I have lots of small files , say more than 20000.

I want to save time spent on mapper initialization, so is it possible to use just 500 mapper , each processes 40 small files as its input?

I need guidance about how to implement this kind of inputformat if possible , thanks !

BTW, I know I should merge these small files, this step is also needed.

Answer (score 3):

CombineFileInputFormat can be used. It's there in the [old](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html) and the [new](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html) MR API. Here is a nice [blog entry](http://blog.yetitrails.com/2011/04/dealing-with-lots-of-small-files-in.html) on how to use it.